# how to enable wordwrap in button in php?

Tags: php, css, mysql

My code is dynamic and takes the value of the button from my database using PDO.

How do I wrap the text (data from database) while it is written in the button. note: It must accept dynamic long lengths of text per button.

here is my code. Where do I attach the `wordwrap` from here ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY btn_id";
foreach ($PDO->query($sql) as $row) { ?> 
    <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg  " value="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>">
    </div>
<?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: May help [PHP Wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) or [CSS Wordwrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Dipu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space: normal;` & `word-break: break-all;` property to make it wrap around the parent container.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg  " value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat maxime debitis repellendus totam, accusantium perspiciatis deserunt harum nemo omnis officiis similique vel quasi explicabo optio, unde sed, vero quia quae?">
        </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It helped me a lot! Saurav :)

Comment: @MigsMartin It's my pleasure!